# React Native : Navigate to a screen "nested inside BottomTabNavigator" from firebase push notificaiton click

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, navigation

This is a part of my BottomNavigator code in App.js.

```
const Bottom = createBottomTabNavigator();
return (
<Bottom.Navigator
  tabBarOptions={...}>
  <Bottom.Screen
    name="ScreenA"
    component={ScreenA}
    options={...}
  />
  <Bottom.Screen
    name="ScreenB"
    component={ScreenB}
    options={...}
  />
  <Bottom.Screen
    name="ScreenC"
    component={ScreenC}
    options={...}
  />
  <Bottom.Screen
    name="Chat"
    component={Chat}
    options={({navigation}) => ({
      tabBarLabel: StringsOfLanguages.chat,
      tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) =>
        focused ? (
          <Image
            style={appStyles.bottomTabImgSize}
            source={require('./assets/abc.svg')}
          />
        ) : (
          <Image
          style={appStyles.bottomTabImgSize}
            source={require('./assets/def.svg')}
          />
        ),
        tabBarButton: (props) => 
        <TouchableOpacity
          {...props}
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate('Chat', {screen: 'ChatSubA'})
          }
        />
    })}
  />
</Bottom.Navigator>
);
```

and this is the code for bottom tab named "Chat"

```
  const Chat = () => {
// Usually ChatSubB is called from ChatSubA.. But on receiving push notification
// ChatSubB should be directly loaded.
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="ChatSubA">
    <Stack.Screen
      name="ChatSubA"
      component={ChatSubA}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="ChatSubB"
      component={ChatSubB}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="ChatSubC"
      component={ChatSubC}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />

    <Stack.Screen
      name="ChatSubD"
      component={ChatSubD}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  );};
```

Say if I want to navigate to 'ChatSubB' screen from ScreenA/ScreenB/ScreenC I am using the code

```
  props.navigation.navigate(Chat, {
screen: ChatSubB,
params: {param1:'hai'},
```

});

But now I need to call 'ChatSubB' on push notification onclick
I don't have 'props' or 'navigate' available to call the above line of code.
This is my PushNotificationHelper.js file. I call these methods from App.js useEffect()

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async- storage';
export async function requestUserPermission() {
  ...
await getFcmToken();}
export async function getFcmToken() {
  ...}
export const notificationListener = (navigate) => {
 messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
    console.log(
      'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
      remoteMessage.notification,
    );
    // navigate("ChatScreen",{
    //     result: "2371820992-5406-07082-13972-17488760826513",
    //   });
      // navigate('ChatScreen', {
      //   result: "2371820992-5406-07082-13972-17488760826513",
      // });
      navigate("Others", {
        screen: ChatScreen,
        params: {result: "2371820992-5406-07082-13972-17488760826513"},
      });
  });}
```

While refering to obtain props or navigate I found a solution using createRef

```
  // RootNavigation.js
import * as React from 'react';
export const navigationRef = React.createRef();
export function navigate(name, params) {
 navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

and use

```
  RootNavigation.navigate('ChatSubB ', {param1:'hai'})
```

But this code doesn't work for me as "ChatSubB" is nested in BottomTabNavigator
tab "Chat".

Is there any other solution to achieve my requirement?
Any help would be grateful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#passing-params-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator) you can navigate like this -

```
RootNavigation.navigate('ChatSubB', {
  screen: 'Chat',
  params: {
    param1:'hai'
  }
});
```

Comment: HI.. sorry for the previous comment.. I have been using the code you have mentioned but screen name was not given inside quotes.. That was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this documentation may help you?
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#nesting-multiple-navigators

And try to use useNavigation hook)